# I am not able to put an object behind a Rounded Rectangle

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, crop, clipping-mask

I am not able to put an object behind a Rounded Rectangle
Cropping results in complete removal of the object to be put behind and clipping a mask produces the same result [image]

Comment: Excuse me, but if your mountains are moved behind an object (= the light rectangle with rounded corners), why you still expect to be able to see the  mountains? Have you tried to make the light rounded rectangle transparent before arranging it into the foreground? Your question has too much rounded rectangles  to be clear enough for proper answering.

Comment: @user287001 Do you see the round corners in the bottom portion of the mountains I want only those parts to be cropped out and want the entire mountain to sit perfectly within the light rounded rectangle

Comment: @sayan9241 But like you said you want the mountains WITHIN the rectangle, not behind. If you take two pieces of paper and put one behind the other you can't see what's written on the back one. (Unless you decrease opacity of the front one, but that's not what you're looking for either). It needs to be in front to be clipped to the rectangle, otherwise you are clipping the rectangle to the shape of the mountains.

Comment: @JaneDoe1337 I want the mountains with-in the rounded rectangle the light blue one now you can see in the screenshot that the light blue rectangle has rounded corners now to place the mountains within the rectangle(in the front of course so that it is visible) I would have to match the radius of the corners of the mountains with respect to the radius of the corners of the rectangle which would be a tedious task so I want to escape that task and successfully place the mountains within the rectangle so how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you start, put the smart guides and snap to point on, disable snap to grid in the view menu.

See the cartoon and the explanations below:

[image]

1) Have 3 identical rectangles and your mountains, nothing is grouped! The rectangles have temporarily black strokes only to make them visible in this image (=1)

2) Drag your objects to their final places. Goto object > Arrange to send objects to bottom or bring them to front. The 3 lowermost in the stack must be the rectangles. The ordering is possible also in the layers panel, which you seem to have got visible in your screenshot.

3) Select the topmost rectangle. Bring it to front. Select with holding shift also the small mountain.

4) Goto Object > Clipping Mask > Make. The foreground rectangle vanishes and the mountain gets clipped. The clipping result pops automatically to foreground, but it will be fixed when you clip the other mountain, which will pop to foreground.

5) Bring again a rectangle to front. Select it and the rightmost mountain.

6) Goto Object > Clipping Mask > Make. The second mountain gets clipped and only one rectangle is left at the background.

You can release the clipping masks as long as you have not expanded nor rasterized the clipped shape

Comment: This is what I needed!

Comment: Ok  I want the two mountains to be separate objects with separate colours so I have grouped both the mountains and I cloudn't understand what do you mean by this ( do steps 3...4 twice.)

Comment: And in step 3 (red color one) how did the mountains went behind the rectangle was it because of the pathfinder panel selection?

Comment: @Sayan have total three copies of the rectangle. One is the final background. One is used to mask the leftmost mountain and one is used to mask the rightmost mountain. Group the mountains after you have done the clippings, if you want a group, not before. About step 3: If you copy something to the clipboard and paste it in place, it becomes the topmost object of all what is stacked to that place.

Comment: what if I group the mountains first then make a copy and in the first place the mountains should be behind the rectangle (If I am right) and then I have to copy and paste it in the front (correct me if I am wrong)

Comment: @Sayan As told, mask one non-grouped mountain with one non-grouped rectangle. Keep all else unselected. You will get better like all others when they practice.

Comment: can you be a little more elaborate?

Comment: can you show in this screenshot https://dbr.ee/3q0q what I have to do?

Comment: @I'll rewrite the answer having two differently colored mountais. I'll do it in 2 hours.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66102/discussion-between-sayan-and-user287001).

Comment: Hurrah! it worked at last you are like a God to me.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you tagged clipping mask in your post I assumed you knew how it worked, hence my comments.

You do not need to give the mountains the exact same border radius in the exact same place as the border of the rectangle, that would indeed be very tedious. You can simply clip the shapes together.

Adobe has an excellent video tutorial on how to do that:
https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/clipping-masks.html

Comment: I know clipping but in SketchApp where clipping is easy but /i am new to Ai so I was having problem with clipping!